# How to go from a date to another date in Date Picker SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, date, swiftui, datepicker, uikit

I have an Date Picker which I want to go from one date to another date. My dates are fetched from a backend, and they look something like this in the backend

```
"2022-01-01T10:30:00".
```

After the call from the function that i wrote, the date looks like this :

```
2022-01-01 10:30:00 +0000
2023-01-01 20:00:00 +0000
```

The problem that i have is that something isn't right, the time in my Date Picker is always started from the current time and is end on current time too

This is the coded for what I have wrote :

```
struct TestView: View {
   
    @EnvironmentObject var syncViewModel : SyncViewModel
    @State var dateFrom = Date()
    @State var dateStart : Date = Date.now
    @State var dateEnd : Date = Date.now
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        let minMaxRange = dateStart...dateEnd
        DatePickerUIKit(selection: $dateFrom,
                        in: minMaxRange, minuteInterval: 30)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        }
        .onAppear {
           dateStart = dateFormatTime(date: syncViewModel.schedule[0].start)
           dateEnd = dateFormatTime(date: syncViewModel.schedule[0].end)
            print(dateStart)
            print(dateEnd)
          
        }
    }
    func dateFormatTime(date : String) -> Date {
            let isoDate = date
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
            
            return dateFormatter.date(from: isoDate) ?? Date.now
        }
}
```

What I want to accomplish :

- to go from this **date** "2022-01-01 10:30:00 +0000" **to** "2023-01-01 20:00:00 +0000"

I tried something like this and it worked fine, but with my dates is not working.

```
let minMaxRange = Date.now...Date.distantFuture
```

[image: Date Picker picture]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dateStart...dateEnd` instead for the date picker interval?

Comment: That is because you are using the `@State` variable instead of your actual value. If you look at your previous question where you ask about using a `String` instead of a `Date` you will see a better way to handle this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yeah, i typed wrong here  on stackoverflow I edited right now